# PHP MYSQL ERROR when inserting data

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, kohana

I'm getting the following error  :

> 2016-04-26 15:11:56 --- DEBUG: Error ocurred where inserting user data to the legacy db :Database_Exception [ 0 ]: [1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1 ~ APPPATH/classes/database/mysqli.php [ 179 ]

For the php query :

```
$result = $usdb->query(Database::INSERT, "INSERT INTO users (id, `password`, group_id , active, created, updated) VALUES ({$user['id']}, {$user['password']}, {$user['group_id']}, {$user['active']}, {$user['created']}, {$user['updated']})");
```

Here are the column types :

```
id : int AI PK
password : varchar

group_id : int

active : tinyint

created : int

updated : int
```

Comment: The `password` field is of type `VARCHAR`, so the value `$user['password']` should be encapsulated in single quotes.

Comment: single quotes or double quotes ?

Comment: Please don't tag both `mysql` and `sql-server`. They are 2 completely different databases, they are not the same thing.

Comment: @apandey, Single quotes.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul I did add single quotes, but I'm still getting the same error ?

Comment: Please add proper escaping for your variables. Otherwise you will be susceptible for SQL injections.

Comment: What does `Database::INSERT` do? Does that build the `insert` part of the query for you (the `kohana` manual won't load for me)? When using a framework they usually have built in methods.

Comment: You've looked at the Kohana manual https://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide//database/query/builder#insert? (Absurd amount of time for any of the pages on that Frameworks page to load)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have single quotes `'` around your values in your SQL query, assuming they're strings (not integers) in the database.

Columns and table references *can* be encapsulated with backticks, though they don't have to, assuming they're not using a reserved keyword. Values, on the other hand, *generally* need single quotes around them (unless, of course, you're preparing your values through prepared statements; or if you're certain the database schema uses the integer type).

Putting single quotes around integers works just as well, so it's probably safe just to surround any value with a single quote, like so:

```
$result = $usdb->query(
    Database::INSERT, 
    "INSERT INTO users (id, `password`, group_id , active, created, updated) 
        VALUES (
            '{$user['id']}', 
            '{$user['password']}', 
            '{$user['group_id']}', 
            '{$user['active']}', 
            '{$user['created']}', 
            '{$user['updated']}'
        )
    "
);
```

### **Note:**

You should ALWAYS be using parameterized queries (prepared statements). It is extremely unsafe to inject raw PHP variables into a SQL query. If you have a variable with a single quote, it will break the logic of your SQL statement.

You can read more about prepared statements in [the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

So what your SQL should *really* look like is this:

```
$sql = "
    INSERT INTO users (id, `password`, group_id , active, created, updated) 
    VALUES (
        :id, 
        :password, 
        :group_id, 
        :active, 
        :created, 
        :updated
    )
";
```

And then bind your actual values into the prepared statement.

Comment: @Sean it's likely that he's using some integer columns, though the single quotes never really hurt, so I figured I'd post something that would work regardless of the details of his schema.

Comment: Looking again at the OPs column types, they are all `int`/`tinyint` except for `password`, so although quoting the other values works, it is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `password` column is of type `VARCHAR` the value `$user['password']` should be encapsulated in single quotes. And since the rest of the columns are of type `INT` or `TINYINT` single quotes aren't necessary.

So your query should be like this:

```
$result = $usdb->query(Database::INSERT, "INSERT INTO users (`id`, `password`, `group_id` , `active`, `created`, `updated`) 
          VALUES (" . $user['id'] . ", '" 
          . $user['password'] . "', " 
          . $user['group_id'] . ", " 
          . $user['active'] . ", " 
          . $user['created'] . ", " 
          . $user['updated'] 
          . ")");
```

You should use backticks (`) for table and column names, single quotes (') for strings. Backticks are only needed when your table name or column name is a [MySQL reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html), but it's a best practice to avoid reserved words.

**Sidenote:** Use [PDO prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) to prevent your database from any kind of SQL Injection.

From the **PDO::prepare**

> Calling PDO::prepare() and PDOStatement::execute() for statements that will be issued multiple times with different parameter values optimizes the performance of your application by allowing the driver to negotiate client and/or server side caching of the query plan and meta information, and **helps to prevent SQL injection attacks by eliminating the need to manually quote the parameters.**